# Complex code/algorithm optimization (e.g. simplification) quandary

Tags: java, algorithm

How can this code be simplified?

```
  if      (x == 0) x = 1;
  else if (x == 1) x = 0;
  else if (x == 2) x = 3;
  else if (x == 3) x = 2;
```

Comment: Simplification != optimization; algorithm != code; KISS;

Comment: "Simplified" judging by which metric exactly? Characters typed? Number of statements?

Comment: @jprete: Judging by the user name I would say yes :-)

Comment: Is `x` guaranteed to be in the range 0-3?  If so, then the `xor` trick is the best. Otherwise I'd suggest the `switch` statement.

Comment: There's no point in trying to simplify this without some context. What is this trying to do? What happens when x is greater than 3? Or less than 0 for that matter? More importantly, why?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably using [switch statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Switch statements are no better than the original. I'd argue that they're actually worse.

Comment: So the last shall be first, and the first last

Answer (score 15):

If x is always between 0 and 3 then try this:

```
x ^= 1;
```

It toggles the least significant bit.

If x can be a value other than between 0 to 3 then you can first test for that:

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 3) {
    x ^= 1;
}
```

Comment: Again, not equivalent: it will also modify `x` when `x < 0 || x > 3`

Comment: Great, I 'll give +1 to that :)

Comment: You can use a bitwise and on all but the 2 least significant bits to avoid two inequality comparisons.

Answer (score 9):

This is the **simplest** form possible:

```
if      (x == 0) x = 1;
else if (x == 1) x = 0;
else if (x == 2) x = 3;
else if (x == 3) x = 2;
```

wait... that's exactly your code.

cryptic one liners are NOT simple.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
int mymap[4] = {1,0,3,2};
```

and then in your code use this:

```
x = mymap[x];
```

Comment: And hope that `x` isn't < 0 or > 3.

Answer (score 5):

To use your pseudocode notation, maybe:

```
if (x % 2 == 0) x = x + 1
   else x = x - 1
```

e.g you are adding one if it is an even number, subtracting otherwise?  In terms of optimization though, I don't see what is particularly slow or wrong with your original code.

Comment: This is not equivalent: it will also modify `x` when `x < 0 || x > 3`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x >= 0 && x <= 3)
  if((x%2) != 0) //odd
    x--;
  else if((x%2) == 0) //even
    x++;
```

Comment: How do you define more "simple"?  This is more "simple" than the original because there are less code paths.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I think this is simpler, and it doesn't limit the case to 0..3, but:

```
x += (x % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x ^= x & ~3 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Unfortunately my code was so simplified it failed to make the 30-character minimum...

Answer (score 1):

A common approach for handling simple data like this is to use the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

The **code** would be more redable with a `switch` statement:

```
switch(x) {
case 0: x=1: break;
case 1: x=0: break;
case 2: x=3: break;
case 3: x=2; break;
}
```

However, it's just about **code readbility**, not algorithmics, nor optimization.

Answer (score 1):

```
x^=1;
```

unless x can be lower than 0 or higher than 3, which the problem specification doesn't state.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( 0 <= x && x <= 3 )
  x ^= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

one liner:

```
x=(x==0)?1:((x==1)?0:(x==2)?3:(x==3)?2:x);
```

Comment: Would be easier to read if it was better formatted and had the parentheses removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( x >>> 2 == 0 )
{   x ^= 1;
}
```

Comment: ... which can be shortened by 1 (non-white-space) char. Puzzle: which one?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this...

```
if(x % 2 == 0){
  x = +x;
}else{
  x = -x;
}
```

Comment: result is totally different from the question